# Debugging with enide in async.series

Tags: node.js, enide

I want to inspect the object residing in variable 'browse_results'? I am using Enide Studio. If I start the opc-ua-client.js file as my node-js-application it seems that the script never hits my breakpoint, but after the script has finished, I can see all my console.log statements. I tried to step over my code, but this did not work either - I am done and never reached the area I want to inspect. Here is the related code snippet.

```
async.series([
// ...,
function(callback) {
    the_session.browse("RootFolder", function(err,browse_result,diagnostics){
        if(!err) {
            // need to inspect browse_result via enide debugger
            browse_result[0].references.forEach(function(reference) {
                console.log(reference.browseName);
            });
        }
        callback(err);
    });
},
// ...
],
function(err) {
    if (err) { console.log(" failure ",err);
    } else { console.log("done!")
    }
    client.disconnect(function(){});
});
```

Comment: Raise bug on github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1 and give exact version of OS, Java, Node.js, Eclipse, Nodeclipse plugin and steps how to reproduce.